# Error installing control v3.0.0 package on El Capitan for Octave

Tags: macos, octave, macports

I recently installed Octave using the binary installer found on this site: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X

I then tried to install the control package using 'pkg install -forge control' but it gave me the error 'pkg: error running `make' for the control package.'. I have gone through most of the threads regarding this error but with no success.

I then tried to use MacPorts to install the control package, I followed the instructions on the wiki page above with some help from this thread: [Installing general package in octave has error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265952/installing-general-package-in-octave-has-error). I believe I succeeded installing the packages because I can see them in the folder tree for Octave and MacPorts says it is installed when using the console.

The problem is that when i run some code in Octave it cannot build as it doesn't know that I have installed any additional packages. Using 'pkg list' in Octave it says that no additional packages installed. I feel like I need to link the two together but I don't know how?

I'll happily explain more if I need to and I hope you can help me out.

Many Thanks,

Sam.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "link the two together" (assuming you mean the binary version of octave and the MacPorts version).

If you have packages installed via MacPorts for the MacPorts version of octave, then they will only be available from the the MacPorts version of octave, so make sure you are running that.

Otherwise, figure out how to install the package with the octave binary version. It seems you require a build environment for this, but installing the command line tools (which you must have done for MacPorts to work) might have already solved this problem.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Re-installing everything purely through MacPorts now. Hopefully this will do the trick. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with gfortan compiler built-in with Octave. To solve this you should install an external fortran compiler. 
Try this:

1. Install Xcode and command line tools for Xcode
2. Download and install a fortran compiler for MacOS, for example: http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-6.1-ElCapitan.dmg
3. Change the fortran compiler path in your octave, to this if you installed the compiler that I suggested in point number 2 you only must to open Octave and type: `setenv('F77', '/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran')`.

And Enjoy Octave for MacOS
[Octave with control package 3.0.0 on MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGPAp.png)

Comment: I am also trying to install the control-3.1.0 pkg in Octave (Mac) on OS X 10.13.4. The latest gfortran for Mac is now v. 6.3. I have installed that and verified it in the Terminal. I ran the setenv command as above from the octave-cli (in terminal) but still get a directory not found error on the pkg install command. What is required to make Octave 'aware' of the changed fortran compiler?

Comment: further to the above: changing to setenv ('F77', 'usr/local/bin/gfortran') worked. the same directory returned by 'which gfortran' in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information for a precise diagnostic, but I had the same error message (and a few more), and re-installing octave from source solved it; see [this link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/4972) for more info, but essentially you can do it by running `brew reinstall --build-from-source octave`.